# How to change the default font family when locale changes using tailwind&nuxtjs?

Tags: css, localization, nuxt.js, tailwind-css, multilingual

I've a **bilingual (Arabic and English)** website built with **nuxtjs** and **tailwind**, arabic is **rtl** language.

tailwind.config.js file:

```
theme: {
  extend: {
    fontFamily: {
      sans: ['Open Sans', 'sans-serif', 'Ubuntu'],
      notoKufi: ['Noto Kufi Arabic'],
    }
  }
}
```

***What I want to accomplish is*** changing the default font family in tailwind when user changes the locale/direction of the website.

I've read the [docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/font-family), and tried *Customizing the default font* section and added this code to css

```
[style*="direction:rtl"]{
   font-family: Noto Kufi Arabic
}

[style*="direction:ltr"]{
   font-family: Open Sans
}
```

but nothing changed.

Comment: Did you tried with `@apply font-sans;` rather than `font-family: Open Sans` ? Also, what do you see in the DOM? Is it not applied?

Comment: @kissu, where exactly should i add `@apply font-sans`, however I feel that the problem is to make font-sans refers to Open Sans when En is chosen and Noto Kufi when Ar is chosen, is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: I wrote where, replace (regarding your initial snippet) in the CSS file. For that, you could probably have a computed regarding the locale of your website IMO. I'm not sure under which conditions your CSS selector is applied but working around that may be a good start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a solution to change the `font-family` according to the selected locale using tailwind.

At a **global.css** file I added this code

```
@tailwind base;

*[dir='ltr'] {
   @apply font-openSans !important;
 }

*[dir='rtl'] {
   @apply font-sans !important;
 }
```

and when changing the locale I use `this.$route.path.includes('en')` to set HTML current direction to `ltr`

Comment: Glad that my approach worked. `@apply !font-openSans` should also work, as [explained here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration#important-modifier).